# Attaching a unique identifier to laravel request

Tags: php, laravel, request

Is there a package for laravel that ads a unique identifier to each request in order to use it also for logs?

For example: I would know that request-id `as12121-1212s-121` had an error and I could look into logs for any errors.

That request-id would be seen in the UI and I could debug when getting a printscreen with the error from the client

Comment: Are you wanting to attach a unique ID to every single request? Or just errors?

Comment: To every single request. This id will be referred to also  in logs and stuff. I would like to do this from laravel. Other solution would be to have a proxy in front of my webserver that ads a header like X-Unique-ID

Comment: For now I found thisp package that modifiers the request from thhe midldleware: https://github.com/lara-middleware/request-id/blob/master/src/LaraMiddleware/RequestId/RequestId.php then I could use something like `Log::getMonolog()->pushProcessor`
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a unique id *per request* you can assign a uuid to the request via global middleware.

For example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class RequestUniqueId
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $uuid = (string) Str::uuid();
        $request->headers->set('X-Request-ID', $uuid);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use $request->fingerprint()

This prints a uniqueid from your request and you can track it

```
public function fingerprint()
{
    if (! $route = $this->route()) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Unable to generate fingerprint. Route unavailable.');
    }

    return sha1(implode('|', array_merge(
        $route->methods(),
        [$route->getDomain(), $route->uri(), $this->ip()]
    )));
}
```

Comment: "Get a unique fingerprint for the request / route / IP address."

Comment: This is not unique "per request", if you hit the same uri, with the same method, etc it will return the same value. There is no time or session component

Answer (score 0):

This package might help

[Laravel Request Logger](https://github.com/andersao/laravel-request-logger)